# Fix the following error: ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update the values from a column in a dataframe with the values from the same column but from a different row.

I tried the following code:

```
m = (dfc['year'] == 2015) & (dfc['max'] < 5.0)
n= dfc['Full_date'] == '28-8-2015'
dfc.loc[m, ['max']] = dfc.loc[n, ['max']].values
```

but it returned me the error from the title.

The dataframe I'm working is like that:

```
    min max Full_date   year    month   day
date                        
2015-08-03  3.89    4.80    3-8-2015    2015    8   3
2015-08-04  3.89    9.50    4-8-2015    2015    8   4
2015-08-05  3.89    6.50    5-8-2015    2015    8   5
2015-08-06  3.89    5.50    28-8-2015   2015    8   6
```

The expected output after the code execution would be:

```
min max Full_date   year    month   day
date                        
2015-08-03  3.89    5.50    3-8-2015    2015    8   3
2015-08-04  3.89    9.50    4-8-2015    2015    8   4
2015-08-05  3.89    6.50    5-8-2015    2015    8   5
2015-08-06  3.89    5.50    28-8-2015   2015    8   6
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: The error is indicating that likely `m` and `n` are a differnt length so pandas has no idea how it should align and wont do so. You need to figure out how to deal with those cases

Comment: can you explain in a few words the expected logic?

Comment: @mozway I want to  substitute the values from the max column in the rows which max values are lower than 5 and the column year is equal 2015,  from the values of max where the column Full_date' has the value '28-8-2015'

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example? There is no 28-8-2015 in your example, also drop all the non relevant columns and provide the expected output

Comment: can you have several times 28-8-2015? What should happen in this case?

Comment: @mozway these date values are unique, so they don't repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you consider the replacement value as a vector while it is a **scalar**. (If it was really a vector you would need to define how to map the values)

You can use:

```
# get replacement value
# here FIRST "max" value matching 28-8-2015 "Full_date"
val = dfc.loc[df['Full_date'].eq('28-8-2015').idxmax(), 'max']

# slice and replace
m = dfc['year'].eq(2015) & dfc['max'].lt(5)
dfc.loc[m, 'max'] = val
```

output:

```
             min  max  Full_date  year  month  day
date                                              
2015-08-03  3.89  5.5   3-8-2015  2015      8    3
2015-08-04  3.89  9.5   4-8-2015  2015      8    4
2015-08-05  3.89  6.5   5-8-2015  2015      8    5
2015-08-06  3.89  5.5  28-8-2015  2015      8    6
```